# Finding the php file which is executed (the name is hidden by .htaccess)

Tags: php, .htaccess, lamp

I've a very weird situation on my own website.

When I try to execute this page: 
`http://www.****.com/Militari/Guida-scelta-.htm`
Or this page 
`http://www.****.com/Militari/Guida-.htm`

I get the same result. Looking to the .htaccess/PHP files it's a completely unpredictable result.

It looks like if the executed php file would make a DB search and try to find the best matching result.

This is on a shared hosting.
How can I find which PHP file is being executed?

The .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^Cinema/Interviste/([^/]*)\.htm$ /Cinema/Interviste/film.php?title=$1
RewriteRule ^Cinema/dvd/([^/]*)\.htm$ /Cinema/dvd/film.php?title=$1
RewriteRule ^Cinema/([^/]*)\.htm$ /Cinema/film.php?title=$1
RewriteRule ^Attori/(.*)\.htm$ Attore.php?name=$1
RewriteRule ^Registi/(.*)\.htm$ Regista.php?regia=$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm $1\.php
RewriteRule filmrecensiti\.xml filmrecensiti\.xml\.php
RewriteRule filmrecensiti2\.xml filmrecensiti2_old\.xml
RewriteRule ^Elenco\sFilm\s(.)\.php Elenco_Film_Recensiti\.php?starting_letter=$1
RewriteRule ^Elenco\sFilm\sRecensiti(.*) Elenco_Film_Recensiti$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.js php_js\.php\?id=$1\.js
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.css php_css\.php\?id=$1\.css
#RewriteRule ^feeds/(.+)$ feeds_items/$1 [L]
ErrorDocument 400 /not_found.htm
ErrorDocument 401 /not_found.htm
ErrorDocument 403 /not_found.htm
ErrorDocument 404 /not_found.htm
ErrorDocument 500 /not_found.htm
```

EDIT

I had missed the .htaccess in the subfolder

its content is

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.htm$ film.php?title=$1
```

I found the problem thanks to your advice.

This helped a lot: `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` or `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']`

Comment: You have not given enough information for us to understand your question.  Maybe posting your .htaccess file will help.

Comment: Is this your site or someone elses? Also, it shoulds like a rewrite rule(s) may be loaded in the `.htaccess` file. Post the file please. In addition, if this is your site, are you using any PHP frameworks? Possibly and MVC style framework?...

Comment: No, I'm using no frameworks..

Comment: Are you looking for `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` or `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` in PHP?

Comment: Comment out this line `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm $1\.php` and retest.

Comment: @anubhava: yes, that is the problem.. now I am trying to understand how to prevent the rewrite rule to match /folder/

Comment: ok good, but what do you mean by `prevent the rewrite rule to match /folder/`?

Answer (score 1):

From what you've posted, the only applicable rule would be `RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm $1\.php` suggesting that `http://www.****.com/Militari/Guida-scelta-.htm` would actually serve up `http://www.****.com/Militari/Guida-scelta-.php`.